# Angular 2 multi select dropdown updated design not working

Tags: angular

I have updated Angular 2 multi select dropdown to 4.6.3 and also included default.theme.css in angular.json.

But my UI looks like [image]

```
<angular2-multiselect [data]="itemList" 
                      [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" 
                      [settings]="settings">
</angular2-multiselect>




this.itemList = [
                          {"id":1,"itemName":"India"},
                          {"id":2,"itemName":"Singapore"},
                          {"id":3,"itemName":"Australia"},
                          {"id":4,"itemName":"Canada"},
                          {"id":5,"itemName":"South Korea"},    
                          {"id":6,"itemName":"Brazil"}                      
                        ];

    this.selectedItems = [
                          {"id":1,"itemName":"India"}];
    this.settings = {singleSelection: true, text:"Select Country"};
  }
```

Comment: Did you add AngularMultiSelectModule ?

Comment: Yes. I have added

Comment: ıt seems css not working can u see any css property in developer console about dropdown